# Julia: Converting GIF frames to PNG

Tags: julia, png, gif

I want to be able to convert gif frames to png in using Julia.

I currently have data that has been save to a 4s gif where every frame is the same (which is strange hence why I trying to convert it) and I want to be able to convert it to a png or to be able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FFMPEG.jl

and run

```
using FFMPEG

ffmpeg_exe(" -i $gif_path -vsync 0 $png_path")
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
using FileIO
img = load("somefile.gif")
save("somefile.png", img[:,:,1])
```

seems likely to work. You'll need the ImageMagick package installed, and ImageIO is recommended but not required for PNG.